# How can I align these 2 elements so that the text is vertically centered to the icon?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I am trying to make the text sit vertically in the middle next to the diamond box with the number like this:

[image: Text aligned centrally to the box]

Currently I have this code:

```css
.diamond {
  width: 50px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  font: 20pt Arial, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #EB008B;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0 50%);
}

.image-txt-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.pf-title {
  margin-right :auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-txt-container">
  <div class="diamond">1
  </div>
      <h4 class="pf-title">BRIDGING / SHORT-TERM FINANCE</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: remove **margin-bottom: 0px;** from diamond class

Comment: I answered that never breaks by changing screen width.try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.diamond {
  width: 50px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  font: 20pt Arial, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #EB008B;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0 50%);
}

.image-txt-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.pf-title {
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-txt-container">
  <div class="diamond">1
  </div>
      <h4 class="pf-title">BRIDGING / SHORT-TERM FINANCE</h4>
</div>
```

I think You want something like this

Answer (score 0):

By writing margin:20px, you add 20px margins.

And with your margin-bottom:0px you remove this margin which means that your text is no centered.

If you only need a right margin you can use margin-right:20px;

```css
.diamond {
  width: 50px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  font: 20pt Arial, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #EB008B;
  margin-right: 20px;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0 50%);
}

.image-txt-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.pf-title {
  margin-right :auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-txt-container">
  <div class="diamond">1
  </div>
      <h4 class="pf-title">BRIDGING / SHORT-TERM FINANCE</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your question has been answered up there. I tried to give a different answer

so i remove the margin from `.diamond` and give padding to `.pf-title`

like this

```css
.diamond {
  width: 50px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  font: 20pt Arial, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #EB008B;
  /* margin: 20px; */     <--- remove
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0 50%);
}

.image-txt-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.pf-title {
  padding: 10px;     <--- add
  margin-right :auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-txt-container">
  <div class="diamond">1</div>
  <h4 class="pf-title">BRIDGING / SHORT-TERM FINANCE</h4>
</div>
```

I hope this help and can be another reference for you

Answer (score 0):

Try this then tell me plz if it works

If you want diffrent size just change
Width AND FLEX AND H4

```css
.diamond {
  width: 60%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  font: 20pt Arial, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex:30%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #EB008B;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0 50%);
}

.image-txt-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:space-evently;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding:0 5%;
  gap: 6%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-txt-container">
  <div class="diamond">1
  </div>
      <h4 class="pf-title">BRIDGING / SHORT-TERM FINANCE</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove margin: 20px from diamond div .. instead add it to the container of both diamond and text ..

Consider adding (margin right to the diamond shape **OR** margin left to h4 ) to create space before text

```css
.diamond {
  width: 50px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  font: 20pt Arial, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #EB008B;
  /*margin: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;*/
  /* Add margin right only*/
  margin-right: 20px;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0 50%);
}

.image-txt-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  /*Add margin to the container*/
  margin: 20px;
}


/* No need for this 
.pf-title {
  margin-right: auto;
}*/
```

```html
<div class="image-txt-container">
  <div class="diamond">1</div>
  <h4 class="pf-title">BRIDGING / SHORT-TERM FINANCE</h4>
</div>
```